# Excel column filer using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I've a .csv file which has the below data

```
   COLUMN 1       COLUMN 2
      STATUS        ID
      Pending       123
       Completed    456
      Expired       789
       Completed    987
        Open        654
        Closed      321
        Completed   159
         Rejected   753
```

The perl script should get the file name from the command line and 1st column ie 'STATUS' should be filtered out for all 'Completed' and should print the values in the 2nd column ie, from ID's column.

output should be like:

456
987
159

Comment: Is the data stored as 'seen here' (one line) or is supposed to be EOL separated?

Comment: It is like in a table with two cloumns

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51282927/edit) so we can actually see the formatting of your input data.

Comment: Don't worry, I've done it for you. Now please show us exactly what output you want.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code! What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? What are you exactly having problems with?

Comment: It would also help to know which Excel reading module you are using.

Comment: Please, could you edit your answer and add the following information: Is the input file plain text one? If so, could you upload it somewhere? or at least part of the data? If It is not a plain text file, what kind is it?

Also, you may add your original script to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've extracted your code from the comment where you dumped it. Please put it in your question (where it is readable!) in the future. But the code you have given us doesn't compile. I had to make a few fixes before I could even run it. Please don't waste our time by giving us broken code to look at!

Here's your existing code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my($input, $line);

if(@ARGV!=1){
  # I've added missing quote marks and a closing semicolon here
  print "\nUsage: <Nmae.pl> <Inputfile Name>";
} # I've added what seems to be a missing close brace here

$input = shift(@ARGV);
# I've added a missing semi-colon here.
open(IN_FILE , "<$input") or die ("Error opening file $input");

while(<IN_FILE>){ # Added missing file input operator around file handle
  $line = $_;
  chomp($line);
  $line =~ s/ //g;
  say $line; # Added missing comma
}
```

This code is clearly written to process a text file. So I'm not sure why you've mentioned Excel in your question. But I've assumed that your code is more correct than your question and have read the data from a text file.

So here's how I've rewritten it to do what you asked for:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

# Errors should go to STDERR, not STDOUT. Also kill the process
# if we have no input. Hence "die", not "print".
die "Usage: <Nmae.pl> <Inputfile Name>\n" unless @ARGV;

# Place to store data we're interested in
my @matches;

# Use empty file input operator to read from files named in @ARGV
# without having to open them.
while (<>) {
  # Look for lines containing "Completed" and capture the
  # following digits
  if (/Completed\s+(\d+)) {
    # Matched digits will be in $1
    push @matches, $1;
  }
}

# Print the matches
say "@matches";
```

Answer (score -1):

I modified your script. It seems that you are loading plain text file, not an excel one.

This should work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV or die "\nUsage: <Nmae.pl> <Inputfile Name>;";

my $input = shift;
open my $fh, '<', $input
  or die "Error opening file $input; $!";

local $/ = "\r";
my @lines;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  # If the line is: Begins with none or more spaces,
  # "Completed" word, none or more spaces, digits
  # then print captured digits
  $line =~ m{ ^ \s* Completed \s+ (\d+) }sxmi
    and print $1 . "\n"; # $1 stores first capturing group ()
}
```

Output:

```
D:\Temp>type aaa.txt
STATUS     ID
Pending     123
Completed   456
Expired      789
Completed   987
Open           654
Closed        321
Completed   159
Rejected    753

D:\Temp>Nmae.pl aaa.txt
456
987
159
```

Edit: Changed answer based on @DEV original script

Comment: You could explain your answer instead of just dumping in the code. That way others can learn from it, rather than just copying & pasting.

Comment: Thanks for you help. My data looks like below      
STATUS, ID 
Pending ,123 
Completed ,456 
Expired ,789 
Completed ,987 
Open, 654 
Closed ,321 
Completed ,159 
Rejected ,753

ie, $input  has the above data

Comment: @Dev: Dumping your data in a comment like that isn't really very helpful, I'm afraid :-)

Comment: Below is the code I tried to print the data from excel file

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my($input, $line);

if(@ARGV!=1){
print \nUsage: <Nmae.pl> <Inputfile Name>

$input = shift(@ARGV);

open(IN_FILE , "<$input") or die ("Error opening file $input")

while(IN_FILE){
$line = $_;
chomp($line);
$line =~ s/
//g;
say $line
}

output:

STATUS, ID Pending ,123 Completed ,456 Expired ,789 Completed ,987 Open, 654 Closed ,321 Completed ,159 Rejected ,753

I want only below to be printed

456
987
159

Comment: Just don't chomp the lines and concat all data inside some variable. Then, use that variable as $input of my script. Or chomp the lines, store them on an array and then forget about the split part.

Comment: @Dev I changed my answer, now it is based on your script

Comment: @Julio, I'm not getting any output for the above script.

Comment: @Dev: Dumping your code in a comment is even less helpful than dumping your data there :-) Please edit your question to add your code.

Comment: @julio, I have updated the question for more understanding. please check

Comment: Hi @Dev, I believe that now it should work. I guess that your file is using MAC line endings. Try with my updated answer.